# How to find a number in a message on discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot on discord and I want the bot to detect how much the person says in his message and who he mentioned, ex. >command @user 7853. I know that

```
message.mentions.users.first().id
```

finds the first-mentioned user but I don't know how to find the number that they said. Can someone tell me the correct script for that?

Comment: Do you mean the [user tag](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag)?

Comment: _"but I don't know how to find the number that they said"_ -> `message.content`

Comment: no, basically I'm making a command where you can "give currency" i just want to find the number that they mentioned in the message, not the user tag

Comment: @elm I assume what you're looking for is parsing the content of the mesasge. You'll need to take the `message.content` and parse it the way you need. Please read [ask] and provide examples of what you get and what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.content` is the content of the message so you only need to parse that like:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift();
```

This will convert the message into an array like `['@user', '7853']`.
Now you can just do `args[1]`  and you will get the number.

If you are interested and want to learn more you can do here: [`https://discordjs.guide/`](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html), this is the guide made by the community of `discord.js` and includes a section about setting up commands you need.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: you have to change the "args[2]" to "args[1]". the question itself is ok but in my .json file the money the person has turns to null whenever I add it to them